# Continue reading not working in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, blogs

I have come across a problem with my code - I have created a customized page and integrated it to Wordpress. In the blog section, I added function:

```
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
    global $post;
  return '... <a class="moretag" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '"> continue reading &raquo;</a>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
```

However, when clicked, continue reading doesn`t show the full post. 
Could you direct me where to look to solve the problem?
Thanks
Mirek

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't show the full post? Do you mean that it does go to a different page but shows the excerpt, or do you mean that the button does not redirect the user at all?

Comment: Sorry for not being specific - button did not redirect at all but I found the solution - I used old syntax - had to rename my old php file to content-single.php and change
<div class="post-excerpt"> to be class "post-body" and change the_excerpt(); to the_content(); and finally just reflect the change in single.php

Comment: I figured it was something like that, but in order to conclude that, this information was important. Anyway, seems like Raf helped you on your way. If his answer helped, you should accept it (little check under the arrows). If not, answer the question yourself (in detail) and accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check content-single.php file. It should contain the_content(); in order to display full post.

Comment: Thanks Raf. I worked with the old syntax. I had to rename my old php file to content-single.php and change
<div class="post-excerpt"> to be class "post-body" and change the_excerpt(); to the_content(); and finally just reflect the change in single.php